# lookup id from Task to custom object with button

Tags: custom-button, button, urlhacking

I have created a custom object and in the task, i have created a detail page button to automatically create the new custom object but including already some information from the task.
my Url looks like:

> https://cs83.salesforce.com/a0P/e?retURL=%2Fa0P%2Fo&00N4E000000W6wU={!Account.Id}&CF00N4E000000WAUy_lkid={!Account.Id}

just to clarify: 00N4E000000W6wU is a text field to check, if the value is correct, which it is
00N4E000000WAUy is the lookup field for Account in the new custom object, which i want to be filled, but this won´t work.

Here is the result URL

> https://cs83.salesforce.com/a0P/e?retURL=%2Fa0P%2Fo&00N4E000000W6wU=001D000001h5hLB&CF00N4E000000WAUy_lkid=001D000001h5hLB

Am i missing something here?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Any specific reason for using URLENCODE?

Comment: googled a lot before posting here and somewhere i found that, but neither solution worked anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `Account.Name` and `Account.Id` for the _lkId

```
CF00N4E000000WAUy={!Account.Name}&CF00N4E000000WAUy_lkid={!Account.Id}
```

Also note, no spaces after or before &

Comment: thx for that, tried different versions already, changed to                                                                           https://cs83.salesforce.com/a0P/e?retURL=%2Fa0P%2Fo&00N4E000000W6wU={!Account.Name}&CF00N4E000000WAUy_lkid={!Account.Id}    but still not working, the Account.Id in the first field is only there for checking, if it in general gets the id

Comment: ok...just read another article, which clarifies to my what you already explained. i should forward both, the name and the id...for me, that means   "cs83.salesforce.com/a0P/e?00N4E000000W6wU={!Account.Id}&CF00N4E000000WAUy={!Account.Name}&CF00N4E000000WAUy_lkid={!Account.Id}  and this is working as expected, thanks

Comment: Yes for a lookup, both name and Id should be passed.  Good to know it worked! cheers!